# Is there any iPhone SE out there with 3D Touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, multi-touch

I have an iPhone SE so does my cousin. A few days ago we went to the movies and I noticed she was 3D Touching her way around the screen.

This surprised me because I don't think my iPhone SE has ever had 3D Touch capability, so when I got home I looked in the settings app but there was no 3D Touch option anywhere. I checked the specs online and found that the

> iPhone SE has a 4" (diagonal) widescreen multi-touch IPS LED-backlit
>   1136x640 native resolution (326 ppi) "retina display" without 3D Touch
>   support

But I know what I saw and my cousin was definitely using 3D Touch.

Is her model a newer series of iPhone SE that has 3D Touch?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are correct, the iPhone SE does not have 3D Touch. What you most likely witnessed is that your cousin was running the iOS 13 Beta and as a result of this, Haptic Touch is now available on some older iPhones that never had 3D Touch.

In terms of what you can do about it, you’re in luck because iOS 13 is now available to the public. All you need to do is upgrade iOS and you’ll have the Haptic Touch support that iOS 13 offers (one that is almost identical to 3D Touch).

That is, in iOS 13 Haptic Touch is now available in most of the ways that 3D Touch was available to 3D Touch devices (previously, in iOS 12 Haptic Touch was limited). However, the way to utilise it is by pressing on the screen continuously for a second or so, as opposed to applying more pressure in the way 3D Touch worked. Because this works on the basis of how long you're pressing, there's no need for special hardware, hence the reason why the iPhone SE can take advantage of this feature.

For more information, see the [iOS 13 info on Apple's website](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-13/).

To upgrade, simply go to **Settings > General > Software Update**.

Comment: Some of it was in iOS 12 also.. say in control panel, long press music block expanded it. received no feedback, but I was happy with it

Comment: Thanks @ankii I've edited my answer to remove some ambiguity re iOS 12 and Haptic Touch.